# Linux- split large files in smaller chunks and append .txt to the smaller pieces

Tags: files, split

I have been trying to split a large file using the `split`command but along with this I need to do the following:

1. split a number of files in a directory
2. add an extension .txt to the smaller chunks

I have tried the following :

```
split -dl 10000 "/root/Dumps/" "/root/Dumps/split/${new%.txt}";
```

but I receive this error

```
split: output file suffixes exhausted
```

and to add the extension I use `--additional-suffix=.txt`

but I receive the following error

```
split: unrecognized option '--additional-suffix=.txt'
```

Edit: The output of `apt-cache policy coreutils` is

```
If 'apt-cache' is not a typo you can run the following command to lookup the package that contains the binary:
    command-not-found apt-cache
bash: apt-cache: command not found
```

Any help?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use * instead of % in `split -dl 10000 "/root/Dumps/" "/root/Dumps/split/${new%.txt}";` because % allows only 1 character.

Comment: @kashish : Getting this error - `${new*.txt}: bad substitution`

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy coreutils`

Comment: Check my answer now

Comment: 11.10 is end of life and so did the support end on askubuntu (so I removed the tag ;-) ) And: what happens if you use more than 1 % (`split -dl 10000 "/root/Dumps/" "/root/Dumps/split/${new%%%.txt}";` ) (have an educated guess on the amount of files you might end up with)

Comment: @Rinzwind : I am divide my large file into 10 pieces for %%% gives me aa upto aj. My actual requirements are the two points I specified in my question. 1. I need to do this spilt over many files 2. I need to add .txt in every pieces of split file.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, either way doesn't work.
So, I just put the code for changing it.

```
split -dl 10000 "/root/Dumps/" "/root/Dumps/split/new; for input in new*;  
do mv $input ${input}.txt;done
```